# How do I write a script to keep retrying Yum Update Program?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, yum

My job let me always release a new version of the program to a satellite server, then in the running server, I use `yum update program` to update the program.

However, due to unknown reason, in most of times, even if I upload the program to the satellite server, `yum update program` can't get the update soon. I always have to wait, keep retrying, etc.

So anyone can tell me how to write a script, so

1. it keeps retrying `yum update program` if no update available
2. if update is available, then the update in yum is forced
3. after successful update, the script quits.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From `man yum.conf` on Fedora 17:

> **retries** Set the number of times any attempt to retrieve a file should retry before returning an  error. Setting this to '0' makes yum try forever. Default is '10'.

So, in */etc/yum.conf*, under the *[main]* section, does it help to define *retries*?

Also, there is a *yum-updatesd* [package](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/yum-updatesd) that can be installed. If it is available, one could edit */etc/yum/yum-updatesd.conf* to enable automatic updates:

```
#do_update = no
do_update = yes
```

And then restart *yum-updatesd*.